# Optimize method Array comparison to fetch item nearest to the specific CGFloat : speed up building

Tags: ios, swift5

This method consumes my compilation time as 34434.5 ms (a.ka 34.5 s) When it comes to compilation and implementation. Would you please tell me the way to speed up compiling such method?

Here is my working

```
extension Array where Element == CGFloat {
    func nearest(to x: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return self.reduce(self.first!) { abs($1 - x) < abs($0 - x) ? $1 : $0 }
    }
}
```

Comment: Compile time or run time? Your question isn't clear.  I compiled this extension in a fraction of a second. If you are talking about runtime, how big is the array?

Comment: compile time. It often takes 10 seconds on average to finish compiling this method.